# List products from current category

Tags: categories, tags, list, plugins

This code is from the archive page and list all products with a certain tag, can someone please help me to modify this code to make listing products only from current category:

```
<?php if ( is_product_tag() ) :?>   
    <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>
        <ul class="products">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        </ul>
    <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: WooCommerce already supports product listing by product category. No need to modify any code at all.

Comment: But I need a filter by category and tag, not only by category

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to show all products within a category that have a specific tag?

Comment: yes, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet to do this would be to add a filter/hook on the specific tag. See this snippet at the WooCommerce API docs site on excluding a category for the proper format and to get going in the right direction. http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/

But if you want a down and dirty way to filter for a specific tag on this content part then you can wrap an *if then* around your woocommerce_get_template_part().

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ( *** product has tag *** ) { ?>
            <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

You can look at the API docs on the product tags at http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_tags

Make sure you're following WooCommerce theme customization recommendations at http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/template-structure/

Unless you want this to be global you'll have to account for the various outputs and determine when you don't want to filter both products and tags.